# SVN Copy Error : 200 OK

Tags: svn

When I am trying to copy a folder from one repo to another repo using the following command

```
svn copy -m "creating  tag " https://URL1/folder1 https://URL2/folder1
```

I am getting this error :

```
SVN : Options of 'https://URL' 200 OK (https://URL)
```

Please help !!

Edit : It seems I cannot use svn copy across repositories. Am I correct? Is there any way I can do this without creating dump and loading back etc?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can not do cross-repository operations. Do **svn export** from one repo and then **svn import** into another.

Comment: Not true, Subversion does support foreign repository copies like this as of 1.8.0.

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you want to do here but you need to be using Subversion 1.8.0 or newer on the client.  I don't think you need a 1.8 server on either of the servers.  There's a [good blog post about this](http://blogs.collab.net/subversion/foreign-repository-copies#.UxEMRscUe5M) by C. Michael Pilato one of my fellow Subversion developers.

I suspect you're either using the wrong URLs or an old version of SVN.

Comment: 1.8.x can do copies from foreign urls to a working copy. But he's trying a copy from one repo to another. I don't think that's possible even with 1.8.x?